# How to insert an image in a HTML page?

Tags: html, image, embedded-resource

Don't hit me too soon!

I know how to add an image in a HTML page... But I want to add the actual image file in this HTML page.

There it is, I want my html page standalone, without any folder or file with it. I put the css in the `<style>` balise for example. Now, I would like to do the same with an image.

First question: Is it possible?

Second question: Is the imported image file could be added more than once in the HTML?

I don't know if I am understandable, so, there is an example of what I want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <file byte="A02AB46213F541F...ABCD542" ref="my_ref" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="my_ref" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This link tells you how to do it: http://sveinbjorn.org/news/2005-11-28-02-39-23/Embedded-image-data-in-HTML-documents.html

Comment: Thank you very much! You answered my first question. Now it could be great if I can make a reference with my embedded resource because I will need this image a thousand time in my HTML page (Second question)

Comment: And for the second question no, I don't think that's possible using data URLs.

Comment: use the img tag .. <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli"> the answer from this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found!

Thanks to... Stackoverflow actualy ^^

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176149/use-a-base64-embedded-image-multiple-times) I found is really simple. Just use the Data Url in the css! Ok so now my html code is really unreadable, but the html file is really simple!

**EDIT :** I though a little example could be great for any others:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .myImage
            {
                background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...ggg==");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myImage">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the data in the src attribute of an img tag.

```html
<IMG  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg....ggg==">
```